# remove space between text words and punctuation mark

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML - three span elements each containing a text element:

**HTML**

```
<span>5</span>
<span>,</span>
<span>000</span>
```

As you can see here there is space between the `5` and the `,` elements although padding and margin equal zero. This is probably due to font containers margins or something like that. How do remove those spaces?

**EDIT**
Thanks to everyone. One important clarification - the span items are added using jQuery's append method so there is no way I can place them in one line

Comment: I don't see any space.

Comment: Did you mean to link us to an example?

Comment: You probably have spaces between the actual span elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent rendered whitespace with float or font-size. No need to change your HTML for spans, but a parent element is necessary.

```css
/* Float method */
.float {
  overflow: hidden /* Or any other method to clear float */;
}

.float span {
  float: left;
}

/* Font size method */
.fontsize {
  font-size: 0;
}

.fontsize span {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="float">
  <span>5</span>
  <span>,</span>
  <span>000</span>
</div>

<div class="fontsize">
  <span>5</span>
  <span>,</span>
  <span>000</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<span>5</span><span>,</span><span>000</span>
```

If you don't want (typographical) spaces, then don't write spaces!

That said, I appreciate this isn't always desirable, especially when writing more complex structures. In such a case, you can (and typically should) minify your HTML before sending it to the browser - personally, I strip all newlines and tabs as "unnecessary" (if I actually want a space, I manually type one) and this works quite well.

Comment: Why aren't you using frameworks? (Cool game idea Btw!)

Comment: @Xatenev Because they're too restrictive. Too bulky. Notice how fast my page load times are (shown at the bottom)? But also, it's psychological. If I use a framework and something doesn't work, I blame the framework (ie. the tools). But because I wrote everything myself, I am the only possible cause of it not working.

Comment: Well, though - working without a framework, highers the chance of getting hacked(in case you are not a security pro). And aswell it increases the development time.

Comment: @Xatenev Actually chances are lower, because when an exploit is found in a commonly-used framework all sites using it are vulnerable but I am safe. That said, you are right, I do have to be careful not to introduce my own security holes! But on the flip side they're a lot easier for me to fix. As for dev time... I like to weigh it against the amount of time it would have taken me to learn the framework ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50866/discussion-between-xatenev-and-niet-the-dark-absol)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks, I add the element with jQuery's append method which doesn't allow to put them on one line. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

used to this

```
<span>5</span><span>,</span><span>000</span>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6pT4a/)**

**2nd option try to this**

```
<span>5</span><!--
--><span>,</span><!--
--><span>000</span>
```

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/6pT4a/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any whitespace between your tags:

```
<span>5</span><span>,</span><span>000</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spans are inline wrappers and inline elements leaves white space. you can try with this

```
<span>5</span><!--
--><span>,</span><!--
--><span>000</span>
```

Or you can do it in one line

```
<span>5</span><span>,</span><span>000</span>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/96ngW/1/)

Comment: When I first encountered this "space problem" years ago, adding comments was my first "solution". It rapidly became an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Cool way of solving this issue though.